# Error in adding the Apache CFX run time in eclipse

Tags: apache, web-services

I am newbie to web services. i am trying to generate stubs using Apache CFX on eclipse. when i try to add CFX in preferences using Windows >> Preference eclipse gives error "Invalid Type Name". i tried to change the JRE from JDK 6 to 7. change the versions of CFX but still problem persists.

Please help in resolve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem because of multiple java version installed on my machine and CFX found two different versions of JAXB. I uninstalled java 7 from my machine and then it worked with java 6.